# API for Reporting

Tags: activecollab

Does the API enable the exporting of activity and task hours estimates (or other custom report data)?

I'm interested in building some custom reporting using exported data, and want to determine if it's worth the trouble to learn how to use the API.

If so, can anyone point me to the best source for how to use an API like this?  I've used Microsoft APIs in the past where you just go to a website and it returns a CSV.

Thanks!

Comment: I looked into Zapier, and it appears that there aren't any Zaps that would help with custom reporting.

Comment: I'm currently building something similar. For us it's an integration with our support ticket system. The documentation that is on the website (https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/) is really bare-bones.

From my experience, I've had to tinker and test things out in order to end up seeing what the full capabilities are.